# search suggestions and other list filter fields

Tags: search, lists, autocomplete, filter, search-suggestion

I have a list and filter. 
Filter contains text field and many checkboxes
When user types something into text field, it provides search suggestions
The question is should search suggestions depend on checked chekcboxes ?
Assume that some record matches value typed in text field but is not related to any of selected checkboxes. Should this suggestion be displayed in dropdown ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what are you going to base your search suggestions on.

**Search suggestions based on earlier (successful) queries** - there shouldn't be relation to checkboxes, but if there isn't any record matching, a balloon may appear telling the user to broaden the search scope by unchecking some checkboxes

**Live search based on typed text** - the relation would be expected, but in this case it is not the search suggestion but displaying first n records matching the search.

I hope it's clear.